# In Firefox, parent element won't get focus when child with fixed position is clicked

Tags: firefox, focus, css-position

I have a fixed element inside a focusable element. When I click the fixed element, the parent focusable element should receive focus. It works in Chrome, Edge and IE11, but it doesn't work in Firefox.

```css
.focusable {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.focusable:focus {
  background-color: blue;
}

.fixed {
  top: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="focusable" tabindex="0">
<div class="fixed">
Parent will not get focus.
</div>
</div>
```

Do you know about any workarounds? I would like to avoid handling mousedown event and calling preventDefault().

Answer (score 0):

because you are using position fixed for the inner child element

removing `position:fixed` and it will work fine

Comment: Of course. But I am talking about elements with position fixed.

Comment: you can't make position fixed relative to any parent element so only way to do it is using relative absolute approach check this for more clearance https://jsfiddle.net/hx7wsgqz/

Comment: That's not the problem, I don't need position fixed relative to parent element.

Comment: it's not possible until you are involving javascript for example https://jsfiddle.net/hx7wsgqz/1/

Comment: And you will end up with something like https://jsfiddle.net/9h3nwr45/5/. It's exactly what I want to avoid. I will try to report bug in Firefox.

Comment: @DusanJanosik sure then :)